# use function between two strings

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Hope you are doing good. I am looking for some help on following.

I have a Share Points list table which has Key_documents column. This column consists many HTML code snippets embedded into DIV and HTML tags as shown below. For some string values the encoding is not looking good (this is coming from source system). I am trying to fix that encoding issues at the query output.

**Data In Table for Key_Documents**

```
<a href="http://tarregsp01p/sites/Regulatory/NextDocs Document Library/VEGF Trap-Eye/Module 5 - Clinical/03 Study Reports/311523 (VIEW 2)/01 Study Report/311523-Report Body.pdf">Year 1 CSR</a></div>
```

**Desired Output**

```
<a href="http://tarregsp01p/sites/Regulatory/NextDocs%20Document%20Library/VEGF%20Trap-Eye/Module%205%20-%20Clinical/03%20Study%20Reports/311523%20(VIEW%202)/01%20Study%20Report/311523-Report%20Body.pdf">Year 1 CSR</a></div>
```

Please find that the *empty spaces* are encoded to `%20` above

I am trying to use `utl_url.escap`e. The issue with this is it is encoding all the special characters which in turn corrupting my HTML code.

Any help? Technically, I would like to use `utl_url.escape` function after `href=` and before `</a>` in above example

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  id, 
  listagg(case mod(n,2) when 0 then utl_url.escape(substring) else substring end)
    within group (order by n) string
from
(
  select 
    id,
    n,
    regexp_substr(string, '(.*?)'||chr(1), 1, n, '', 1) as substring
  from 
    (select id, 
       regexp_replace(string, '(href=")(.*?)"', 
       '\1'||chr(1)||'\2'||chr(1)||'"')||chr(1) string 
     from your_table), 
    (select level n from dual connect by level < 999)
  where 
   regexp_substr(string, '(.*?)'||chr(1), 1, n, '', 1) is not null
)
group by id
order by id
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2d0d3/4)